# Touchend event (JS) is not working on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, events

I have a code where whenever user touch on the comma (,) key, the entire input will turn into a tag. Here is the code below:

```
var tags = new Array();
    document.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
        if(e.which==',' || e.which=='188'){
            if($("#pre_tag").is(':focus')){
                var tagO = $("#pre_tag").val();
                tagO = tagO.replaceAll(',','');
                if(tagO!=''){
                    if(tags.includes(tagO)==false){
                        tags.push(tagO);
                        $("#pre_tag").val('');
                        $("#tags").append('<button class="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-light tagID" data="'+tagO+'">'+tagO+'<span class="badge badge-pill badge-light">x</span></button>');
                    }else{
                        alert('This tag is already selected!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But the code is not working. I've tested on my mobile phone. Is there any solution?

I want to make it work on the mobile phone.

Comment: The [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) property is deprecated and perhaps not supported by your mobile phone's browser.

Comment: Why on earth would `e.which` be a comma or 188 for a `touchend` event?!